# How to transform/format scientific notation number to 2 decimal cases?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have this function below, that iterates through sheets in a excel workbook, and gets the data into a pandas dataframe. Unfortunately some of the values are coming in scientific notation, and I need them rounded to 2 decimal cases

```
def iterate_sheets(wb, number_of_fw=13):

# iterates through each sheet in the workbook
for sheet in wb.sheetnames:
    ws = wb[f'{sheet}']

    i = 0
    while i < number_of_fw:
        cel = ws[f'A{10 + i}']
        cel.number_format = '#,##0.00'
        fiscal_weeks.append(cel.value)
        i += 1
    i = 0
    print(fiscal_weeks)
    while i < number_of_fw:
        cel = ws[f'B{10 + i}']
        cel.number_format = '#,##0.00'
        pageloads.append(cel.value)
        i += 1
    i = 0
    print(pageloads)
    while i < number_of_fw:
        cel = ws[f'C{10 + i}']
        cel.number_format = '#,##0.00'
        tti.append(cel.value)
        i += 1
    print(tti)

    platform_name = ws["B2"].value
    metric_name = ws["C8"].value

    # transform the data into a pandas DataFrame
    data_dict = {
        'fiscal_week': fiscal_weeks,
        'pageload': pageloads,
        'tti': tti,
        'metric_name': metric_name
    }

    df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
```

Comment: Hello, try this out `df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].round(2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.2f' % x)
```